# Meaning of a Brownian Motion being independent of a probability space

Tags: probability-theory

The following statement is in my text:

> Let $B'$ be a one dimensional Brownian Motion on the probability space $\{\Omega',\mathcal F', P'\}$ that is independent of the probability space $\{\Omega,\mathcal F, P\}$.

What does this statement mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the author is implicitly building and working with the [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) of the probability spaces whose corresponding measure $\mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P}^\prime$ satisfies $$(\mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P}^\prime)(F \times F^\prime) = \mathbb{P}(F) \mathbb{P}(F^\prime)$$ for all $F$ in $\mathcal{F}$ and $F^\prime$ in $\mathcal{F}^\prime$.

**Intuition**. Imagine $X$ is a random variable in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ corresponding to a coin flip. Knowing that $X = \text{Heads}$ does not reveal anything about the realized sample path of the Brownian motion. Similarly, the Brownian motion reveals nothing about the coin toss.

Comment: How do we know that $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal F'$? ie: How do we know $\mathbb P (F')$ exists?

Comment: You have written $$\mathbb{P}(F \cap F^\prime) = \mathbb{P}(F) \mathbb{P}(F^\prime) $$ but how do we know $ \mathbb{P}(F^\prime)$ exists?

Comment: @alpastor: Sorry, that was a mistake. Fixed.